# How to add Meta tags for 404 error page in Laravel 5.4

Tags: php, http-status-code-404, laravel-5.4, meta-tags, custom-error-pages

I want to update the `meta tags` of my `404 error page` i.e. 404.blade.php of my Laravel 5.4 website.

404.blade.php page is located at path: `\resources\views\errors`

All the other pages that I have build having controller from where I am easily passing `meta title, meta description and meta keyword` and using them in my front design common file as shown below.

```
<title>
@if(isset($title))
    {{ $title }}
@endif
</title>

@if(isset($meta_description))
    <meta name="description" content="{{ $meta_description }}">
@endif

@if(isset($meta_keyword))
    <meta name="keywords" content="{{ $meta_keyword }}">
@endif
```

But in the case of 404 error page, I don't have any controller from where I can pass its meta tags. So left clueless how to add meta tags for 404 error page.

Please help me!

Comment: To do above job, I have added another design layout error-design.blade.php specially for 404 Error page and added all meta tags there but I don't think this is the right way and still looking for better solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have added another design layout error-design.blade.php specially for 404 Error page and added all 404 meta tags there. Now its working fine.

Answer (score 0):

```
<title>
@if(isset($title))
    {{ $title }}
@endif
</title>

@if(!isset($meta_description))
    $meta_description = '404';
@endif
<meta name="description" content="{{ $meta_description }}">

@if(!isset($meta_keyword))
    $meta_description = '404';
@endif 
<meta name="keywords" content="{{ $meta_keyword }}">
```

You can try something like this.

Comment: $title, $meta_description and $meta_keyword are dynamic. I am passing them from related controllers and in case of 404 Error file, I am searching for that in-built controller only from where I can pass these tags.